# Setup SharePoint development environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, 2016

I'm trying to setup development environment for the latest version of SharePoint in my office Laptop for learning purpose. I do not want to install the SharePoint on my local machine? What are my best options?

Can you spin a SP 2016 VM online and do all my development stuff there?

Could someone chime in your suggestions?

Comment: I know you said you don't want to host anything on your computer, but I personally use Hyper-V on my Windows 10 desktops and it works great. I have several sysprepped Development environments, but I don't know the best way to share 35-45 GB with everyone. My latest envrionment has VS2017, VSCode, Pre-installed SQL Server, preinstalled ActiveDirectory, SQL Management Studio, preinstalled SharePoint 2016.

Answer (score 7):

**Unfortunately,** There is no `SharePoint Server 2016 online Lab` available now!

**Based on your requirement, you can prepare SharePoint 2016 environment through the below options:**

- If your own PC specifications match the [minimum Hardware requirements. For SharePoint 2016](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements), so try to

  - [Install SharePoint 2016](https://blog.devoworx.net/2015/09/03/install-sharepoint-2016-preview-single-server-farm/) on VMware / HyperV from scratch.
  - Or [download SharePoint Server 2016 Virtual Machine.](https://gauravmahajan.net/2017/10/06/sharepoint-server-2016-virtual-machine-download/)

> **Note:** there is no SharePoint Foundation free version in SharePoint
>   2016. for more details check [SharePoint Foundation 2016 What's the alternative?](https://blog.devoworx.net/2017/01/23/sharepoint-foundation-2016-whats-the-alternative/)

- If you have Azure Subscription, you can configure [SharePoint Server 2016 dev/test environment in Azure](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/sharepoint-server-2016-dev-test-environment-in-azure)
- If you want to work with SharePoint Online, so you must have [Office 365 subscription](https://products.office.com/en/office-365-home) , there is no VM for SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 3):

Up until yesterday (Expired May 25th) you could use a prebuilt SharePoint 2016 VM in Azure. I expect they will either release an updated one soon, or wait a month or two and release a SharePoint 2019 version.

You can use any cloud host service (such as Azure) to build a SharePoint 2016 VM using the trial versions of the SharePoint software (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51493). If you remember to turn off the VMs when not in use, the cost can be quite resonable.

If your PC/laptop has enough RAM, you can build a test environment using HyperV or VirtualBox. While the "requirements" are much higher, I do my development with a VirtualBox VM with only 12 GB of RAM. It runs SP2016, SQL, Visual Studio, and other tools. (I install and run the test browsers and SharePoint Designer outside of the VM.)

Answer (score 1):

As a SharePoint developer, I have followed many online guides and books on how to setup Sharepoint for development purposes over the years.

In my opinion, Stacy Simpkins book:  [Building a SharePoint 2106 Home Lab](https://www.apress.com/it/book/9781484221693), is the best and will get you success if you follow it.  All you need is a machine with 16G of Ram, an MSDN license helps and some time to read through it and set it up.  You will learn a lot about the SharePoint platform.

You will learn more if you build it yourself using a good book or guide.  Spinning one up online with a script on Azure or AWS is great, but you won’t learn the different components that make up a SharePoint Farm  as you do when you build your own lab.

Answer (score 0):

If you have NSDN license you can Build a farm on Azure DevTestLabs. There are a couple of templates available.